# .jar from netbeans will not open in console

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, console

Built a simple java program in netbeans, build/compiled it and it generated a .jar for me in the project directory.

The following is my src code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Welcome {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Welcome to Java");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    }

}
```

I want to be able to open this in console to use the scanner function, but I can't seem to open the jar.

I have tried opening it from the command line with the following:

```
java -jar "C:\Users\Nick\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\dist\JavaApplication1.jar"
```

But no dice. Double clicking the .jar doesn't open it either.

Any ideas here?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to build it as a runnable jar if you want to start it with -jar

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

> You can run JAR packaged applications with the Java launcher (java
>   command). The basic command is:
>
> java -jar jar-file
>
> The -jar flag tells the launcher that the application is packaged in
>   the JAR file format. You can only specify one JAR file, which must
>   contain all of the application-specific code.
>
> Before you execute this command, make sure that the runtime
>   environment has information about which class within the JAR file is
>   the application's entry point.
>
> To indicate which class is the application's entry point, you must add
>   a Main-Class header to the JAR file's manifest. The header takes the
>   form:
>
> Main-Class: classname
>
> The header's value, classname, is the name of the class that is the
>   application's entry point.

The alternative is to run it using by specifying the classpath and the main class

```
java -cp "C:\Users\Nick\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\dist\JavaApplication1.jar" Welcome
```